# react-native auth0 sign in with apple?

Tags: ios, react-native, auth0, sign-in-with-apple

How to sign in with apple in react-native using auth0 web form authentication?

Tried following this guide: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/apple-siwa/set-up-apple?_ga=2.267694410.553381554.1591475612-866095660.1584309547

But no luck. Testing the connection gives me: invalid_redirect_uri.

One problem with guide was this part about creating service id:

"After checking Sign In with Apple, click on Configure and define your Web Domain (example.com) and your Return URL. Make sure that your Return URL is your Auth0 domain, such as foo.auth0.com (or your Auth0 custom domain if you have one) and follows this format: https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/login/callback. "

Since I use react-native, the callback is not an url that starts with 'https', but a custom uri to return users back to the application. Apple won't allow me to put that custom uri when creating the service-id, but requires the https prefix.

Has anyone succeeded in implementing sign in with apple for react-native applying the auth0 web authentication? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I decided to ask, I got this solved.

Problem was that I was just copy-pasteing the login callback from my auth0 app's configuration directly. Instead of actually doing what reads in the guide.

So I changed the login callback to just follow this format: https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/login/callback

And it works now.

Comment: hey, do you have any sample code on how did you pass the apple authorization code to auth0? seems that i cannot find any documentation about this on auth0.